# Javascript Convert int value to octet stream Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, int, modbus

I want convert an integer (signed) to 32 bit (big endian) into a octet stream and give the octet stream as a array value to the constructor of a
Buffer Object.

I can create it in the console for example for the value -2000:

```
<code>
buf = Buffer(4)
buf.writeInt32BE(-2000)
buf // is <Buffer ff ff f8 30>
buf1 = new Buffer([0xff, 0xff, 0xf8, 0x30])
</code>
```

The value -3000 is for example -3000 : 0xff ,0xff, 0xf4, 0x48

But the framework i use accepts not the writeInt32BE function and throws exception.

How can i convert a 32 bit integer value signed to a octet Array stream without the writeInt32BE  ?

A function that takes a value and returns an array of octet stream.

Comment: `Buffer` is a global supplied by Node, not the framework. So you should not be getting an exception  for `(Buffer instance).writeInt32BE()` with valid parameters. What _exact_ code causes the exception, is it running in Node and what is the framework?

Answer (score 1):

Using a 4 byte array buffer, converted to a data view and calling setInt32 on the view seems to work. This approach supports specification of both little endian and big endian (the default) formats independent of machine architecture.

```
function bigEnd32( value) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var view = new DataView(buf);
    view.setInt32( 0, value);
    return view;
}

// quick test (in a browser)
var n = prompt("Signed 32: ");
var view = bigEnd32( +n);
for(var i =  0 ; i < 4; ++i)
    console.log(view.getUint8( i));
```

Documentation was located searching for "MDN ArrayBuffer" "MDN Dataview" etc. Check out [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) in detail for properties that access the underlying array buffer - you may be able to tweak the code to suite your application.

Comment: when i print it with getInt32(i) it causes RangeError: actually i want convert -2000

Comment: the underlying buffer contains 4 octets. `view.getInt32(0)` returns it's value as a 32 bit integer. Passing a non zero offset to getInt32 will cause a range error. `+n` in the test code converts a string to number, not a negative number to a positive one. -2000 gives 0xff 0xff 0xf8 0x30 as expected.